# How do I display Form Validation Message at Bottom Page

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am making a feedback form which uses JQuery to check for form-validation.
If the user clicks the Submit button without providing any of the fields / giving an invalid input for my "rating input" (string...etc)

How do I display the message after the submit button in `bullet-point` instead of it being beside my input?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Feedback Form</title>
        <script src="script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#indexForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        name: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        email: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        rating: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        remark: {
                            required: true
                        }

                    },
                    messages: {
                        name: "* Please enter a valid name",
                        email: "* Please enter a valid email",
                        rating: "* Please enter a valid rating (number)",
                        remark: "* Please enter a valid remark",
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            #indexForm label.error, #indexForm input.submit {color: red; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="doAddItem.php" method="post" id="indexForm">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Full Name:</td>
                    <td><input id="id_name" name="name"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td><input name="email"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Remarks: </label></td>
                    <td><textarea name="remark"></textarea></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Ratings: </td>
                    <td><input name="rating"></td>
                </tr>    

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe you can achieve what you desired by using a custom errorPlacement function option.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: You know that link-to's answers without a valid example (or showing where OP's code is failing from what was *possibly* tried) are discouraged on SO. I think you've been around long enough to know that ;-)

Comment: It worked, thanks :)
May I ask how do I ensure that the input for ratings is a number?